# Nextjs Api endpoint is not executing middleware

Tags: fetch, next.js, passport.js

I have an api endpoint which runs some passport.js middleware and returns a user object if logged in.

When i visit the endpoint through the browser it works, but when i use fetch inside getServerSideProps, it returns empty.

The middleware doesn't seem to execute... any thoughts?

/api/auth/loggedin

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import auth from '../../../middleware/auth'

const handler = nextConnect()

handler
  .use(auth)
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user)
    res.json({ user: req.user })
  })

export default handler
```

/pages/account

```
...
export async function getServerSideProps(context)  {
  let res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/api/auth/loggedin`)
  res = await res.json()

  console.log(res)
  return {
    props: {}, // Will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use fetch to call your own API in `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps` or `getStaticPaths`. The code is always executed server-side, and thus you should directly call the methods instead of the api.

This could be something you want to do client-side instead? There it would be ok to do the fetch.

When to use getServerSideProps: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops

Don't fetch inside getServerSideProps etc: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directly